# Run a query at specifec time daily

Tags: node.js, postgresql, real-time, feathersjs

I am working on a car rental application , my question is so simple . but i can't express it
Now whenever an order is inserted , i need a task runner that keeps running on all the orders . and keep adding the daily rate into the total due field

For example if today is 17/9

```
OrderStartDate   RentalAmount     TotalDue
17/9/2020 17:00        100              0
17/9/2020 16:00        100              0
```

18/9 16:00 field will be like

```
OrderStartDate   RentalAmount     TotalDue
17/9/2020 17:00       100              0
17/9/2020 16:00        100             100
```

18/9 17:00 field will be like

```
OrderStartDate   RentalAmount     TotalDue
17/9/2020 17:00        100             100
17/9/2020 16:00        100             100
```

my appilcation is a react + nodejs(gql,prisma,nexus)
I made a research for the realtime applications using web sockets , feathers-js but didn't find exactly what i need

Answer (score 1):

You could use a MySql EVENT or TRIGGER to do this.

However, there's a much better way. Rather than change certain rows and columns in place when other rows or columns are INSERTed or UPDATEd, use a query to generate the sums when you need them. For example,

```
SELECT rental_id, SUM(rental_amount) total_due
  FROM rental
 GROUP BY rental_id
```

Another way to do it is with a running-total query. You should read about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule a job which runs daily (or every minute, hour anything), means at a given interval always.

These are called cron jobs,

there are libraries to do this like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron, detailed example https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-in-nodejs/

Or you can schedule a job on server scheduler too (better approach)

Comment: and this actually my concren . is there a way to make every order in my table syncronised with it's start date ? . If i scheduled a job on server scheduler . this will run daily or weekly basis . i am searching for something that runs on a custom time for every order